# Force Number Keyboard on Text Input

Tags: html, regex, forms

I have an `<input type="text">` element, which I have decided to use instead of `type="number"` so that I can format currency with commas, and I would like to use the number keyboard for my mobile users.  The [existing solutions I have found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6753600/iphone-development-how-to-display-a-numeric-keyboard) require a `pattern="[0-9]*"`, but I need a pattern for my validation as well.

[Codepen here](http://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/xElCm).

How can I use the number keyboard without changing the `pattern` of my input or the `type`?

Comment: You cannot *force* a numeric keyboard, and the odds of having it successfully *suggested* are small if you want to use `input type=text`. I’m pretty sure this question has been asked before at SO.

Answer (score 0):

Although it doesn't work yet on mobile browsers (keyboard still remains text), [we may be able to use the `inputmode` attribute to set the keyboards on `text` elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input).

[I have done up a codepen to test this](http://codepen.io/srsgores/pen/qFajs) (not working in latest chrome on Android).  Perhaps we will see this implemented in the near future.