# Text input to bring up capitalized on screen keyboard

Tags: asp.net, .net, html, css, html-input

The site is being used on Android tablets.  I have included the following in the input's css class:

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

This does its job in that letters typed do appear as upper case in the input.  But it is not causing the on screen keyboard to come up with capitalized lettering.  The keyboard letters appear as lower case even though they type upper case in the input.  So the issue is not so much functionality as the text is in upper case when typed. It's more for consistency and creating a seamless feel for the user who is typing upper case letters with a lower case keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find this is something which can't be set in CSS, but must instead be set using the SDK in a dedicated app.

Comment: Thanks.  Any examples or links that could help me with that? The aspx page is actually being used in a WebView in an Android application, so the app already exists.  I'm just not sure what you mean by setting it using the SDK.  I don't want ALL inputs or EditTexts to appear with the capitalized characters.

Comment: There seems to be a suggestion that setting the "type" attribute of the textbox will help, although I'm unsure of the actual value.

https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/130837/android---open-default-soft-keyboard-in-number-view

and 

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

Are really it.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  Type attribute is definitely helpful when trying to bring up numeric keypad, but not so helpful with text case.  I have an idea that I think might work but could be more code than is worth the trouble.  Was just hoping there was an easy attribute or css property that would help.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if `pattern="[A-Z]*"` would do, since according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/1677517/51685 `pattern="[0-9]*"` triggers numbers-only mode on iOS.

Comment: Ah well, it was worth a shot! Good luck though. :)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure about a Android but on web pages you can use .onblur() javascript to make them JavaScript. So when the field focus exits it will execute

Comment: The issue is not with making the input itself display upper case letters.  It is when the input is focused the tablet recognizing it is an all caps input and displaying an all caps keyboard.  The fact that the input displays in uppercase already was made pretty clear in the OP.